# AFNetworking not receiving response data

Tags: ios, json, web-services, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking to GET request by posting json object. But i am receiving empty value. I am using the following code.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

NSDictionary *params = @ {@"email" :user_name, @"password" :pass_word };
[manager GET:HOST_URL parameters:params
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    NSDictionary *weather = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

}
      failure:
 ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     NSLog(@"opstr%@",operation.responseString);
 }];
```

What method i should use. If i use POST, i am getting error saying that "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.)

When i use GET i am getting response as empty. I am not sure where i am wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It means that your request response is not a valid json. You can correct the web service to return proper json. Or remove the following line

```
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
```

because it is converting response to json.

To allow fragments, change the code to following

```
[manager GET:HOST_URL parameters:params
  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
 id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject
                                            options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                              error:&deserializingError];
NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
NSDictionary *weather = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

}
  failure:
 ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
 NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
 NSLog(@"opstr%@",operation.responseString);
}];
```

Comment: Do i need to use GET or POST method.

Comment: It depends on your web service. Did you check the response now? I have edited answer to allow fragments in json response.

Comment: getting following error -[__NSCFDictionary bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb2c35f7460'

Comment: your response is not a proper json. can you give me url?

Comment: url has only the following data {"data":"Hi"}. I am getting it without passing parameter. But what i want is whatever i am sending (username and password) i should get the same. web service returns the same.